# socket.emit truncate my object

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am sending an object using `socket.emit` where `socket = io()`

```
    obj = { username: username, 
        key: key, 
        height: window.innerHeight, 
        width: window.innerWidth, 
        x: it.clientX, 
        y: it.clientY,
        h: 4444, em: em()
    };
    socket.emit('mouseMoved', obj);
```

when I receive that object from other end using

```
socket.on('moveMouse', (data)=>{
```

this data object does not contain `h` and `em` elements. Somehow the object is truncated.

Then I changed object's `x` element name to xp

```
    obj = { username: username, 
        key: key, 
        height: window.innerHeight, 
        width: window.innerWidth, 
        xp: it.clientX, 
        y: it.clientY,
        h: 4444, em: em()
    };
```

now the `x` value is also gone, only `username, key, height, width` and `y` values are there. `xp, h` and `em` is not available.

what could be the reason. is there something like "configuring message template" that I should define the message format first.

Comment: what, exactly, does the variable `obj` contain within the call to `socket.emit()`? Can you show us a console.log ?

Comment: @RandyCasburn {x: 568, y: 275, width: 654, height: 279, id: "Pzl3ZS0fuTnZu8a1AAAV"}

Comment: Then the object has been mangled prior to sending, not **_when I receive that object from other end_**. Can you clarify?